# Simple query needs to move to a model

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

I have a simple mysql query I need to put in my admin. It shows a list of  banned customers, as well as their name, notes field, and email.  We have queries all over the place in this antiquated rails 2.3 app. Although I'm new to rails, I'm pretty sure this needs to live in the Customer model.  I know how to build the table in the view, I'm just not sure on the syntax for the model, should it be a named scope, instance, yata yat ya...any recommendations or help would be more than welcome!

```
SELECT first_name, last_name, notes, email_primary
FROM customer
WHERE banned = 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A named scope is appropriate:

```
class Customer
  named_scope :banned, :conditions => {:banned => true}
end

Customer.banned # returns a collection of banned customers
```

Comment: In that vien shouldn't this return a list of first names?                  <% Customer.banned do |b| %>
  <%= b.first_name %>
<% end %>

Comment: I put that on the admin page and nothing gets put

Comment: My apologies, you need an each on there. <% Customer.banned.each do |b| %>